# What is the technical term for animation of a dead body?

Tags: animation, udk

In some 3D games when a 3D model of a person is shot to death (or suddenly dead) his body falls to the ground and every limb, the head and the body move free.
What is this particular way of handling dead bodies called?
Is it possible with UDK?

If you didn't understand, I meant [like in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlxOe43GRHw&feature=fvwrel): see how the corpse falls.

Comment: I believe you're looking for the term [Animate Dead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/animateDead.htm). ;)

Comment: Well yes that or zombification

Comment: Dance of the Dead would be quite appropriate here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called [Ragdoll physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragdoll_physics). However, I have no idea if it's possible to use it with UDK

Comment: Its definitely possible with UDK. Just google UDK ragdoll tutorial. I haven't done that but I'm sure you'll find something

Answer (score 2):

Yes, UDK can do ragdoll physics. You have to use the PhAT ([Wiki Doc](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/PhATUserGuide.html) and [Video Tut](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/VtmPhAT.html)) to create a ragdoll for your mesh.

You can look at UTPawn.uc for how to link the PhysicsAsset into the mesh, and then you can look at PlayDying() or PlayFeignDeath() to see how to turn the ragdoll on.